# ripping audio cd gives different checksum. Real? fake? Underlying reason?

Tags: error-correction

Today I was talking about ripping CDs with a colleague, and the fact that if you rip the same CD twice the md5sum is different. This is what I personally experienced, and I knew out of reading around, but I am not well informed about the underlying hardware reason for this. To be fair, I start to question even my experience, which could have been the result of a mistaken execution of the cd ripping program.

Do you know if this makes sense from the hardware/error correction point of view, and what is the underlying hardware reason for unreliability of audio cd data extraction?

Answer (score 5):

Errors occur all the time when reading CDs. A CD contains additional information to correct read errors to a certain level (Reed-Solomon Error Correction). But if there are too many bits which can't be read, i.e. because of scratches, there's a problem.

With CD-ROMs errors are not tolerated; even 1 single bit error may render a complete database useless or cause a program to crash. You really need every bit to be correct, that's why CD drives retry to read data a few times before giving up and displaying an error message if they can't.

With audio CDs it's different. You can't spend a few seconds retrying to read the data because the audio stream will be interrupted. That's why the decoder will interpolate erroneous bit sequences, a process which is inaudible in most cases, only when the CD is badly damaged you may have dropouts. Which bits are interpolated may be different each time the CD is read, resulting in a different checksum every time.

Answer (score 4):

In almost all cd readers today, there is a system to correct data from a missreading from the CD. If a single data is not available, the hardware can interpolate the last and the next data in order to find a good aproximation to the lost data.

From a human point of view this is unnoticable and the sound seems to still be the original one.

From the PC point of view, any data modification can change the MD5sum completely.

[This site](http://home.btconnect.com/geffers/cd.html) explains how the data correction occurs on the cd.

[This site](http://web.ncf.ca/aa571/daefaq.htm) has some more information about digital audio extraction (DAE).

Comment: Audio CDs have very little error correction data. The CD format was designed when extensive error correction was to expensive to implement (1980s). There is software that tries to make as accurate a reading as possible (EAC, http://www.exactaudiocopy.de/ comes to mind)

Comment: But if only one integer of data was changed, the MD5sum is completely different. I'm guessing that it is one or two bits that are changed.

Comment: if there's an embedded time/date stamp in the file, that will hose checksum reproducibility